# OLS model fit question and interpretation

Tags: regression, least-squares

First I want to say that I am very new to this field with have been self-teaching.

I'm trying to find if there's a relationship between the DIX values that are greater than 0.45 and SPX returns (7-day, 14-day, and 30-day).

First I started by plotting the scatter plots and the first impression is that they do not have a strong relationship between the two as shown below.

[image]

Then I used the OLS model to fit my data and have the summary shown below.  [image]

From my understanding is that because the p-value for the Jarque-Bera test is below than my specified significance level of 0.05, I should reject the null hypothesis that the data is normally distributed.

So my question is that can I even use the OLS model to fit my model given that the data is platykurtic?

- If so, can I conclude that there's a very weak (close to none)
  relationship between the two variables and move on to the next hypothesis?
- If not, what are some consequences of using the OLS to fit my model?
- Any suggestions or tips for me to improve?

Comment: The DIX values (where there are SPX return values) look like they are log normally distributed, i.e., a histogram of their counts would have a right-skewed tail.  Thus, run a histogram of the single variable DIX, and see if it has a longer right tail.  (you can also see that the number of values thin out with increasing DIX value).  If so, maybe use log(DIX) as the predictor and then rerun.

Comment: @user0123456789  Because the scatterplot already exhibits a near-linear relation, transforming the explanatory variable (DIX) won't make any appreciable difference.  Moreover, because the range of DIX is so narrow on a relative scale--the endpoints 0.45 and 0.53 represent a range of only $\pm 8\%$ relative to the middle--taking logarithms will do almost nothing to change the distribution. The concern about data distribution is about that of the *residuals,* not the explanatory variable. Apart from a couple low outliers, the residuals look fine, so transforming the response won't help.

Comment: @user0123456789 Re your claim of "stalking:" not at all.  I generally keep up with all posts, so when you began a flurry of activity a couple of hours ago I happened to see most of your answers and comments as a matter of course.  As in the present instance, I felt it would be useful to upvote the good posts (I did!) and respond to the others in order to prevent misunderstandings.  To the extent your (or anyone else's) posts appear to be unclear, misleading, or incorrect, expect to see constructive responses--if not from me, then someone else.  That's how this site is supposed to work.